# How to get notified when an application moved to trash or an application trashed in mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Get the notification when application moved to trash.
Track the trash when an application added to trash

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106325/how-to-use-ukkqueue-in-a-cocoa-application) to watch the folder ~/Trash for file modifications. When you find that your app folder is moved you can fire an action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: I got solution form here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300998/tracking-file-renaming-deleting-with-fsevents-on-lion